# Fixed point of isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help with the following problem:

Suppose that $T(x)= A(x) + b$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $A$ is a non-trivial rotation. Prove that $T$ has a fixed point: that is, there is a point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(p)= p$.

I was thinking proof by contradiction, but I can't see how I could make any real progress.

Comment: Yes you are. The question specifies that we have a non-trivial rotation, i.e the corresponding matrix is not the identitiy matrix.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$
Ax+b=x \quad \iff \quad (I-A)x=b
$$

And if $A$ is a non trivial rotation than $I-A$ is invertible and the fixed point is $x=(I-A)^{-1}b$

---

The rotation $A$ of angle $\theta$ is represented by a matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta&-\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So:
$$
I-A=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\cos \theta&-\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & 1-\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $\det (I-A)=2(1-\cos \theta)$ is null only if $\theta=2k\pi$, i.e. if $A$ is the trivial rotation. So, if $A$ is not trivial $I-A$ has a not null determinant and it is invertible.

If $b=0$ than  $A$ is a pure rotation that has the origin as fixed point.

Comment: Why must I - A be invertible? What if b=0?

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's usefull :)

Comment: Does the matrix (I - A) being invertible mean that our equation Ax + b = x has a unique solution?

Comment: Yes. $Ax+b=x$ is the same as $(I-A)x=b$ because $b=Ib$, $x=Ix$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, so $Ax+Ib=Ix \iff Ib=Ix-Ax \iff (I-A)x=Ib=b$. The last equation is a linear system that has unique solution iff the determinant of the coefficient matrix $I-A$ is not $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. You were really helpful!

Comment: regarding the added answer: you haved proved that if $\theta = 2k\pi$, $A$ is the trivial rotation. This is slightly more than asked but may still be interesting: under what circumstances does a FP still exist if $A$ is the trivial rotation?

Comment: @Syd:   If $A(x)=x$ than $T(x)=x+b$ is a translation, that does not have a fixed point if $b\ne 0$